# Request group object with the user

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I'm actualy learning Symfony and I'm making my own UserBundle for the reason that I have to use an online API to manage the users. So I joined the User and Group objects with doctrine ManyToOne relation. For the moment all is working properly.

Symfony is actualizing the User object on each page and getting the id of the group (cf. var_dump) but I want from Symfony to get the entire Group object on each page and not only the id of it.

```
User {#467 ▼
  -id: 104
  -uuid: "~"
  -username: "~"
  -lastLogin: null
  -websiteActivity: null
  -clientToken: "1c667ad4-07e2-4ffa-8db1-9997eadbbc4b"
  -accessToken: "b183f850ce4d4decb07cb7485c1d0a88"
  -dataCheck: DateTime {#457 ▼
    +"date": "2017-08-27 18:23:31.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  -reputation: 0
  -group: Group {#456 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: false
    -id: 4
    -inheritId: null
    -name: null
    -chatColor: null
    -websiteName: null
    -websiteColor: null
     …2
  }
}
```

If you know how to do that It would be really helpfull.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - the looks like the User object is returning a Group object there as you're expecting

Comment: It's not returning the entire object but only is id beacause Symfony only get the User on each page. The Group object should not be empty.

Comment: Notice how it is not initialized - that is because you're doing a `var_dump()` of the User object without any joins to the Group entity.  I bet if you do `var_dump($user->getGroup()->getName())` you will get the value you are expecting and then Group will be initialized, because Doctrine will then load that entity with another query.  Essentially you're using `var_dump()` to debug and not understanding the underlying layer.  Also, use `dump()` instead; it was introduced in Symfony 2.6 and is much better.

Comment: I mean I can call this on all my controllers but it would be really repetitive beacause I'll need it on almost all my pages. That's why I'm looking for another way to do that. (nb: I'm using dump)

Comment: I would need to see how you're calling it.  Is it automatically grabbed with the ParamFetcher or are you grabbing it directly from the EntityManager?  If you show how you're doing that I can help.

Comment: (Tell me if I'm talking about the wrong thing) The User object is actually automaticaly generated on each page by Symfony itself who knows that the user is loged in and which determinate the "active" user entity on the session that you grab like that $this->getUser() on a controller.

Comment: I get what you're saying now - check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `$this->getUser()` on a controller is an alias to the following:

```
$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

You can have a look at [Using a Custom Query to Load the User](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user).  You could use that to automatically join to your Group entity:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u, g')
        ->leftJoin('u.group', 'g')
        ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

This was [previously documented](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#improving-performance-with-a-join) in Symfony versions <= 2.5 but was [removed from the documentation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/5184) for clarity and potentially because it wasn't needed for most cases.  If you want you can also move this to your `UserRepository` (if it exists) and call it from there.

This would take effect when the user logs in.  Try that to see if your Group object will be automatically retrieved.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !

Thank you !

Comment: Is it possible to load the user by this function with the id instead of the username ?

Comment: Well, the function says `loadUserByUsername()` and usually takes place when the user is logging in by their email or username, but there's no reason why you couldn't also pass the ID to this function and update your query to search `->where('u.id = :id)->setParameter('id', $username);`

Comment: After reading lines after lines the short documentation and a lot of attemps it's not working, I still only get the User object without the Group. It's not calling this function at all.

Comment: If you're debugging, it's only going to call this method when you initially login.  You should check that this function is being called ; I don't think it will happen on every request.  Make sure that's happening first.

Comment: I'm actually using Guard as login method so I never call this function beacause I only have to send the User object to tell to Symfony wich user is connected. But I can show you that a request is done on every page to get the user object https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/175326249823109121/351496440322719744/unknown.png

Comment: Okay - then I would say you need to find wherever that query is called and override it...without knowing more about your set up I'm not sure where that would be.

Comment: Hey ! After some research I found out how to create a custom user provider (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html) with a function named refreshUser where the function loadUserByUsername is called so I guess it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: The query I want is executed right now but I have an other problem, after intializing the user on login, I get instantly disconnected beacause of an AuthenticationExpiredException. And I clearly don't know how to fix it actually.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a new question :) I'm guessing you'll run into some things like this coding the User system yourself

Comment: I guess yes. At all, thank you for the help you provided me, hopefully there are pe0ple like you to help :D